# Cannot Identify Schematic Symbol

Tags: symbol

I am looking at a VGA to HDMI conversion circuit, and right near the HDMI connector is an array of these symbols:

[image: mysterious schematic symbol]

By the values posted by these symbols, it looks like some sort of capacitor, but I have never seen this strange backwards-z symbol before, and hours of internet searching have given me no clarity.  Is this some odd, alternate symbol for something common?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is a varistor symbol.  People use several and this is one.

Comment: It must be a very uncommon iteration; a quick search on varistor symbols doesn't include a single image of this symbol.

Comment: It's not the most common, but I put "varistor" into bing Images and found a few examples.  It might also be something very similar to a varistor but a little different technology.

Comment: I just tried Bing, and got a good result in the first twenty images.  Strange that Google let me down so badly!

Comment: That's why Bing is my favorite :^)

Answer (score 0):

They are ESD suppressors such as Panasonic [EZAEG2A](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/AWD0000/AWD0000C23.pdf).

Panasonic uses the bipolar Transient Voltage Suppressor (TVS) symbol on their datasheet, perhaps explaining the Dx designators, but I think they're actually just varistors.